# Creating a Custom Polygon Class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oop, polygon

I want to make a custom `polygon shape` class, which i can drag and drop unto my form at will (just as it is done in the case of `OvalShape` and `RectangleShape` objects in VS toolbox). I checked [site1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [site2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [site3](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1033.html), one of which specifically said that the `OnPaint` Event of my form should be overridden. Is there any way I can achieve the same while creating the custom polygon shape, and still have my polygon appear on the toolbox?

Edit:
@Jens: I'll like the control to generate its code with the following tested code:

```
    Me.ClientSize = New Point(24, 24)    
    Dim r1 As Integer = Min(cx, cy) - 10
    Dim r2 As Integer = Min(cx, cy) \ 2
    Dim pts(9) As Point
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9 Step 2
        pts(i).X = cx + CInt(r1 * Cos(i * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
        pts(i).Y = cy + CInt(r1 * Sin(i * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
        pts(i + 1).X = cx + CInt(r2 * Cos((i + 1) * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
        pts(i + 1).Y = cy + CInt(r2 * Sin((i + 1) * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
    Next i
```

That gives me a star with 5 spikes. How can i store them in the Points variable created,

OR

store the points as a region so that whenever i change `forecolor`, it fills the region (i.e. polygn) with the selected color. I also want to prevent painting the `backcolor`. Please take a look at the links below to a c# solution of what i really want, but i suck at converting c# to vb.

[link1](http://www.filefactory.com/file/5o8419kqo1jp/ShapeControl_CodeProject_29Apr2014.zip); [Link2](http://www.filefactory.com/file/6rvn5ngucm5b/ShapeControl_CodeProject_29Apr2014-noexe.zip)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this for WPF or WinForms?

Comment: You need to forget about this, these Shape classes have very fancy designers that make them *look* like controls at design time, even though they are actually components.  Microsoft was conservative about that, like they usually are with non-trivial designers, they are all internal and cannot be reused.  Rewriting them is a pretty major endeavor, use a decompiler if you want to take a shot at it anyway.  Code is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VBPowerPacks\v12.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Design.dll

Comment: The definition of a Rectangle says the following : Public Structure Rectangle
     Member of System.Drawing
Summary:
Stores a set of four integers that represent the location and size of a rectangle. For more advanced region functions, use a System.Drawing.Region object.

Comment: @Jens, it's WinForms.   @Hans Passant, thanks for the link. I have only ~v10.0 folder and it doesn't have the file in your link above. As a hint, i previously installed both VS2008, 2010 and 2012, but after uninstalling '08 and '10, i still have them displayed in my `All Programs` list under `My Computer`. How do I go about restoring v12.0 folder and its files?     @jdweng, thanks for the hint. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that that is what you want. You can always derive a new class from `Control` and use its `Paint` event to draw whatever you like. In your case a polygon.

The control therefore contains a `Points` property that is just an array of `PointF` values that define the edges of the polygon. By using the `DesignerSerializationVisible.Content` attribute you make it possible to edit these values through the designer directly. The code looks like this:

```
Public Class PolygonControl
    Inherits Control

    Private _Points(2) As PointF

    <System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property Points As PointF()
        Get
            Return _Points
        End Get
        Set(value As PointF())
            _Points = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LineColor As Color = Color.Black

    Public Property LineWidth As Integer = 2


    Private Sub PolygonControl_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)
        If Points IsNot Nothing AndAlso Points.Count > 1 Then
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
            Using b As New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
                Using p As New Pen(b, LineWidth)
                    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(p, Points)
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I added a color and width property as well. This is just to give you a rough idea. Notice the attribute above the Points property.

In "action" it looks like this:

[image]

Adding better designer support is certainly possible, but I have no experience with that whatsoever. But it is a start.

**Edit**
Since you always draw the same shape, you can precalculate the points in the control's constructor and just draw the shape in the paint event:

```
Public Class StarControl
    Inherits Control

    'Storage for the shape's points
    Private pts(9) As Point

    'Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(24, 24)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent

        'Precalculate the shape
        Dim cx = CInt(Me.ClientSize.Width / 2)
        Dim cy = CInt(Me.ClientSize.Height / 2)

        Dim r1 As Integer = Min(cx, cy) - 10
        Dim r2 As Integer = Min(cx, cy) \ 2
        ReDim pts(9)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9 Step 2
            pts(i).X = cx + CInt(r1 * Cos(i * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
            pts(i).Y = cy + CInt(r1 * Sin(i * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
            pts(i + 1).X = cx + CInt(r2 * Cos((i + 1) * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
            pts(i + 1).Y = cy + CInt(r2 * Sin((i + 1) * PI / 5 - PI / 2))
        Next i

    End Sub

    Public Property LineColor As Color = Color.Black
    Public Property FillColor As Color = Color.Gold

    Public Property LineWidth As Integer = 1

    Public Sub PaintMe(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        'Draw the precalculated shape
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        Using b As New SolidBrush(FillColor)
            e.Graphics.FillPolygon(b, pts)
        End Using

        Using b As New SolidBrush(LineColor)
            Using p As New Pen(b, LineWidth)
                e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(p, pts)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

For an even cooler effect move the shape calculation into the Paint event handler so the shape resizes itself based on the control's size. This allows you to draw stars of arbitrary size.

Comment: @Le_Buzz That's even easier then. Just calculate the points in the constructor and draw them in the Paint event. See the edit. I draw it twice to achieve a filled shape with variable edge color. Completely transparent background is not really easy to achieve in WinForms. See this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943454

Comment: Thanks @Jens. I noticed that when i change the `LineColor` or `FillColor`, I'll have to click the parent control or the `StarControl` before the change can be effected. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Le_Buzz Call `Me.Invalidate` in the properties setters. I leave that to you ;-)

Comment: you are a hero! Took me hours to pull off, but it was worth the try. Thanks a lot, once again!

Comment: Good to hear. Have fun with the stars